# How can I check if my video card is installed properly?

Tags: drivers, video, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu and my video card is GeForce FX 5200.
I have installed some drivers from the software center and they installed successfully, but the PC is still very slow and when moving windows for example, I see some artifacts, which makes me think the video card is not properly installed. Also there is a huge lag with online videos. I understand my PC is old but I can't stand the fact I can't watch a video online.

How can I verify if video card is installed and working properly with Lubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Type in:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

and you should get output like:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

In your case it should be NVIDIA Proprietary Dtiver instead of Intel

Comment: I get "VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] (rev a1)". Does that mean it is installed?